# How do I output the first negative value in a large .csv using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to find the first negative value in a given column in huge (5 million line) `.csv` files.

```
Import-Csv .\filename.csv | select "column_header" -First 100 | Select-String '-'
```

works well enough, but there are 50 of these files and the `-First 100` is occasionally more than `-First 3000`. This is a job I'll have to do again as we add to it as well. I think the best thing to do would be to pipe this to a function that has some code that does:

```
while(!Found){
     if(value.beginsWith("-")) write-output(value); Found=true; break;
}
```

but I don't know how to stop the input to the pipe (if this is even a feasible way to do it!). It is important that we don't read through the entire file (but 5-10k lines would possibly work) - that takes FOREVER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should get you the first negative result in "Column_Header" and stop after that. Not 100% this is the most efficient way tho, but it should work fine.

```
Import-Csv .\filename.csv | ?{[math]::Sign($_."column_header") -eq -1} | select -First 1
```

Some context for the `math.Sign` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=net-5.0

Returns:

| Return value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | value is less than zero. |
| 0 | value is equal to zero. |
| 1 | value is greater than zero. |

Comment: Close Enough!!! `Import-Csv .\filename.csv | ?{($_."column_header").substring(0,1) -eq '-'} | select -First 1 | select "column_header"` because they put units on the cell values instead of the headers.

Comment: `$_."column_header"` is not the header, it's the value of that header at the current position of the loop.

Comment: I agree! And you can't cast `1.234 yr` to number, so while your solution failed, it provided enough for me to figure out how to do it.